# Java BigInteger Memory Optimization

Tags: java, optimization, biginteger

I'm trying to find LCM of given N numbers. But this code of mine takes more than 32Mb memory. What kind of optimization can I perform here?

```
import java.util.Scanner ;
import java.math.BigInteger ; 
class Main {    
    public static BigInteger LCM( BigInteger a , BigInteger b ) {
        BigInteger c = a.gcd( b ) ;
        return a.multiply( b.divide( c ) ) ; 
    }
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner( System.in ) ;
        int n , t , ind , i ;    
        t = s.nextInt() ;
        for( ind = 1 ; ind <= t ; ind++ ) {
            n = s.nextInt() ;
            BigInteger res = BigInteger.ONE ;
            for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) {
                BigInteger a = s.nextBigInteger() ;
                res = LCM( res , a ) ;
            }
            System.out.println( "Case " + ind + ": " + res ) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Input :

```
2
3
2 20 10
4
5 6 30 60
```

Sample Output :

```
Case 1: 20
Case 2: 60
```

Comment: Do you need a BigInteger here? Wouldn't long suffice?

Comment: if you don't to handle values greater than 2147483647 (2^31 - 1) use an int.  if you don't need to handle values greater than 9223372036854775807 (2^63 - 1) use long.

Comment: @CoolBeans No as N could be 1000. Where each of these numbers could be in between 1 and 1000.

Comment: What's the largest input number you're expecting?

Comment: LCM of 1000 numbers each of which is less than 10000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should try a good arbitrary precision math library like apfloat: http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/
Another way is to implement an algorithm with lower space complexity. :)

Factorise all of them and multiply all prime factors with the greatest exponent. If all numbers are less than 10000, you can use primitives, and then do the multiplication with BigInt. This means far less objects to be created.

Comment: +1 for using alternate algorithm. The OPs method is not a good method for finding LCM of 1000 numbers each of which is less than 10000

Answer (score 2):

This program is not taking 32MB of anything. All of the classes of the JVM put together and their associated heap storage might be 32MB. Or, adding on the overhead of the JVM process, your OS might report it's using 32MB.

The most proximate answer is: you're not going to reduce this memory overhead by changing your program.

If you're running out of memory, well, give it more memory. `java -Xmx1g` lets the heap grow very large, to 1GB if it wants.

Answer (score 1):

Use BigInteger.ONE, not new BigInteger("1"), but 32Mb isn't much really, practically any Java code takes that.

Comment: It's an online judge problem. I'm getting memory limit exceeded. Memory limit is 32Mb. Is there any way to minimize memory?

Comment: I mean is it possible to minimize number of operations or to take a different approach so that the memory resides within 32Mb?

Comment: @caso but I've already made a suggestion about that. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Same result. Memory limit exceeded.

Comment: This is a good change, but, is not going to change memory requirements. It saves you creating some garbage, but, that's easily GC'ed.

Comment: @caso Same remark applies to all the BigIntegers. I don't believe anything is going to change the memory requirements here. 32Mb isn't so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java garbage collector to get `accepted`. Just call `System.gc()` after printing the solution for each case. Here is the modified code -

```
import java.util.Scanner ;
import java.math.BigInteger ; 
class Main {    
    public static BigInteger LCM( BigInteger a , BigInteger b ) {
        BigInteger c = a.gcd( b ) ;
        return a.multiply( b.divide( c ) ) ; 
    }
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner( System.in ) ;
        int n , t , ind , i ;    
        t = s.nextInt() ;
        for( ind = 1 ; ind <= t ; ind++ ) {
            n = s.nextInt() ;
            BigInteger res = BigInteger.ONE ;
            for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) {
                BigInteger a = s.nextBigInteger() ;
                res = LCM( res , a ) ;
            }
            System.out.println( "Case " + ind + ": " + res ) ;
            System.gc();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have to do this often then it might be a good idea to rethink the approach.

You might be able to statically create a data structure for factors of numbers 1 to 10000 and traverse it to quickly compute LCM of all numbers.

Its a guess but I think both your memory usage and speed should improve.

Comment: -1.  This will give the correct output, but it will not save memory (which is what the question is about.)

Comment: @finnw I assume you did an analysis of memory usage? Appreciate if you can share it.